# How to dynamically allocate an 2d array to a struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I'm trying to dynamically allocate an array on the heap using a structure that has a pointer to an array and a string. Here's my code.

```
    struct StudentRecords
  {
     string names;
     int* examsptr;
  };


    void main()
  {


const int NG = 5;

string names[] =  { "Amy Adams", "Bob Barr", "Carla Carr",
                     "Dan Dobbs", "Elena Evans"
                   };

int exams[][NG] = 
{ 
    { 98,87,93,88 },
    { 78,86,82,91 },
    { 66,71,85,94 },
    { 72,63,77,69 },
    { 91,83,76,60 }
};

StudentRecords *data = nullptr;
(*data).examsptr = new int[][NG];

int *data = new int[NG*NG];
```

Comment: You should fix the indentation that probably occurred when copying+pasting into StackOverflow to make the code easier to read. Also note that [`void main` **is not** valid C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-main)

Comment: You are using `*data` when it is a `nullptr`. That will fail before you reach the struct. Oh, and you have two variables called `data`. Not going to work either.

Comment: Are you condemned to a manual memory management? Since it's a homework you could be. But if not, simply use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of `vector`s of `int` (or simply a `std::vector<int>` and don't bother.

Comment: Why did you make your array have 5 columns but only provide 4 values for each row?

Comment: This whole idea is awful; even if you don't want to use container classes you should just have `int exams[NG];` in each `StudentRecord` rather than using a pointer

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of problems with your current code.

```
StudentRecords *data = nullptr; //here you set data to nullptr
(*data).examsptr = new int[][NG]; //then you dereference nullptr, BAD

int *data = new int[NG*NG]; //then you declare another variable with the same name, BAD
```

You should rename one of your variables and set student records to an actual instance of StudentRecords.

You can't dynamically allocate a 2D array in one step like 'new int[rows][cols]'. Instead you either need to allocate a 1D array with rows*cols elements and do maths to convert a row and col into an index of the 1D array or you need to allocate an array of pointers, where each pointer points to an array holding the data. To hold the array of pointers you need a pointer to a pointer, so you need to make examsptr an int**.

You then need to allocate the arrays that are pointed at by the array of pointers in a loop.

EG:

```
//cant be nullptr if you want to dereference it
StudentRecords *data = new StudentRecords(); 

//data-> is shorthand for (*data).
//allocates array of pointers, length NG
data->examsptr = new int*[NG]

//now make the 2nd dimension of arrays
for(int i = 0; i < NG; ++i){
    data->examsptr[i] = new int[NG];
}
```

Comment: @immibis: It's not an array of arrays, but it is one of several ways of implementing the concept of a 2D array.

Comment: edited the answer a bit to avoid ambiguity, I realize an array of pointers is not the same as a stack allocated 2D array.